# Magento delete attribute values/options MySQL

Tags: mysql, magento, attributes

I have an attribute that has thousands of options.
The options are created programmatically by a script that imports all my products from a feed.
The site is running pretty slow, so I figured I'd get rid of all the outdated options.
The problem is that I'm unable to load the edit page form the magento admin.
How can I identify the attribute options with a MySQL query? 
Or how can I delete all the attribute options programmatically?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

this will give you the list of all options

```
$attribute_code = 'color';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product',$attribute_code);
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

and this allows you to update attribute and remove options

```
$options['delete'][$option_id] = true; 
$options['value'][$option_id] = true;

$options['delete'][$another_option_id] = true; 
$options['value'][$another_option_id] = true;

// (...)

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$setup->addAttributeOption($options);
```

Comment: Pavel,

Thanks for your answer. I'm a beginner so I need a bit more help please. How can I use this script to delete all the attribute options? If I need to write in every attribute options it will take hours.

Thanks

Comment: You can get list of all options for the attribute with the first script. As I understood you have list of outdated options, you can write loop that checks if value (label) is outdated and add delete flag to this option. At the end - run `addAttributeOption()` method.

Comment: or you are looking for the full solution?

Comment: sorry for not being clear. I can safely delete ALL the options because next time the feed gets updated the necessary options will get created. so how do i delete all the attribute options?

Comment: so why not to delete and recreate entire attribute?

Comment: Because 1)I can't even load the attribute page. 2)I need to keep the same setup (I believe I can do that)

Comment: Also, I want to be able to programmatically delete all the options to keep my site lean and clean.

Comment: Got this answer here http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/303093/   `$entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId();
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
      ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.entity_type_id', $entityTypeId);
      ->join(
                array('additional_table' => 'catalog/eav_attribute'),
                'main_table.attribute_id NOT IN additional_table.attribute_id'
            );

foreach ($collection as $attribute) {
   $attribute->delete();
}`   Thanks Pavel for the first step.

Answer (score 1):

Here, I am explain you how to delete all attribute option value programmatically in magento. you can also delete the attribute option value from the admin panel of the magento but if there are so many attribute option value then it takes so much time to delete from the admin so you can add attribute option value programmatically in magento. For that you just need to create deleteattributeoptions.php file in your magento root folder add put below code in it And Replace the **ATTRIBUTE_CODE_HERE** with your attribute code.

```
<?php

require_once 'app/Mage.php';$app = Mage::app('admin');umask(0);
$attribute_code = 'ATTRIBUTE_CODE_HERE';
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
$optionsDelete = array();
foreach($options as $option) {
if ($option['value'] != "") {
$optionsDelete['delete'][$option['value']] = true;
$optionsDelete['value'][$option['value']] = true;
}
}
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->addAttributeOption($optionsDelete);

?>
```

I hope it will help you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query that shows the relations to the tables that are involed. I hope this helps. You can get them for each store view individually this way.

To fetch the label to a store view of an attribute (or anything else that is stored inside these tables) use:

```
SELECT 
    EA.attribute_id,
    EA.entity_type_id,
    EA.attribute_code,
    EAL.value AS label
FROM `magento_eav_attribute` AS EA
    INNER JOIN `magento_eav_attribute_option` 
        AS EAO  ON EAO.attribute_id = EA.attribute_id
    INNER JOIN `magento_eav_attribute_label` 
        AS EAL ON EAL.attribute_id = EA.attribute_id
WHERE 
    EAL.store_id = 0 AND
    EA.attribute_code = 'color' LIMIT 0,1';
```

To get the option value that is related to your option to handle use something like this:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `magento_eav_attribute_option_value` 
    WHERE store_id = 0 
       AND option_id = YOUR_OPTION_ID;
```

Or use some joins to connect these tables directly

```
SELECT
      EA.attribute_id,
      EA.entity_type_id,
      EA.attribute_code,
      EAOV.option_id,
      EAOV.value_id,
      EAOV.value,
      EAL.value AS label
      FROM `magento_eav_attribute` AS EA
      INNER JOIN `magento_eav_attribute_option` 
          AS EAO  ON EAO.attribute_id = EA.attribute_id
      INNER JOIN `magento_eav_attribute_option_value` 
          AS EAOV  ON EAOV.option_id = EAO.option_id
      INNER JOIN `magento_eav_attribute_label` 
          AS EAL ON EAL.attribute_id = EA.attribute_id
  WHERE
  EAOV.store_id = 0 AND
  EAOV.option_id = YOUR_OPTION_ID AND
  EAL.store_id = '0' AND
  EA.attribute_code = 'color';
```

I know this is not a way to delete your values, but maybe it helps you to identify a way to fetch the datasets you need.

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I go about doing it

```
// Deleting attribute options by GUID

$setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$attribute  = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "position");

//Values have to be deleted one at a time
// Eav Setup.php
$updates = array();
foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions() as $option) {
        $update['value'] = array();
        $update['delete'][$option['value']] = true;
        $update['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getId();
        $update['value'][$option['value']] = true;
        $updates[] = $update;
}

$setup->addAttributeOption($updates);
die();
```